# Angular 13 routing not working showing new route component below previous comopnent

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In Instructions component when we click on Submit routes it to Confirmation component.

But on  UI it is showing instructions component and confirmation component changes.

Below is screenshot page inspect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Car.png)

Comment: I found out that the culprit of the issue was the BrowserAnimations module in my app.module.ts. By removing it from my imports it the problem went away.

Comment: BrowserAnimation module and router both has nothing to do each other. You have some any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a new Module, and you have declared a the new route on this module, but angular do not recognize the route. It may be since you forgot to add the new Module on the import section of your `app.module.ts` file.